# Javascript confirm return false if cancel

Tags: javascript, confirm

I have a Delete button like so:

```
<a class="btn btn-default" href="Communities.php?action=delete&id=' . $value['rb_communityId'] . '" onclick="javascript:confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this item?\');">Delete</a>
```

if the user clicks cancel on my confirm back, then I want nothing to happen, is there away if the user clicks cancel it will return false.

Comment: That is the default behavior of confirm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<a
  class="btn btn-default"
  href="Communities.php?action=delete&id=' . $value['rb_communityId'] . '"
  onclick="if(!confirm(\'Are you sure you want to delete this item?\')) return false;"
>
  Delete
</a>
```

Key line that changed is the onclick, where the confirmation has been wrapped in an `if(!...)` to catch the occasions where cancel is clicked, and returns false if that happens.

Answer (score 13):

`javascript:` is *not* needed in an `onclick` handler, because you are *already* in a JavaScript context.

`return`, however, *is* needed to pass the return value of `confirm` to the handler. When Cancel is clicked, `false` is returned, which then gets passed to the handler and this cancels the default action (of following the link).

Finally, NEVER use `<a href="...">` for a *delete* action. GET-method requests should *never* change things on the server, *especially* not delete stuff. Use a form and a POST method.

Comment: A strong `+1` for the never get GET-methods not changing things on the server.